# div jumps out of header with short names

Tags: html, css, header

Working on a website where I am thinking to make the name as a variable to show who is logged in but the problem is that the log out buttom goes out of the header when the name is short as Petter, but stays inside when the name is long as Petter Hansen. Is it a solution to make the buttom stay at same position independent of the name size?

`jsfiddle`: http://jsfiddle.net/85tU2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/85tU2/2/

I've tidied up a few things - basically, moved the divs around because you are using `float:right`. Your code was using margins to move the button to the right of the name. So in the css, I've done this:

```
#formtekst {
    position:relative;
    float: right;
    margin: 1px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:#ccc;
} 
#form-group {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
    margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;
    background:#ddd;
}
```

And for the html:

```
<div id="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="NIH.gif" alt="logo" />
</div>
<div id="form-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn">Logg ut</button>
</div>
<div id="formtekst">
    <p>Logged in as Petter</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey ,**

you can just easily change the styles for the *#formtkst* to this

```
  #formtekst {
float: right;
margin: 1px 15% 0px 0px;}
```